# Use Newton's Binomial Theorem to prove series

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, newton-series

Verify that for all integer $n\ge 2$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n-k}=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
(Hint: Consider Newton's Binomial Theorem.)

=================================

EDIT:

From Newton's Binomial Theorem:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x)^p &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}
p \\n
\end{pmatrix} x^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
So,
\begin{eqnarray*}
A: (1+x)^\frac{1}{2} &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \\k
\end{pmatrix} x^k\\
B: (1+x)^\frac{1}{2} &=& \sum_{k=n}^\infty \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \\{n-k}
\end{pmatrix} x^{n-k}
\end{eqnarray*}

I assume finding $A-B$ will lead to the answer $0$ but I'm not sure how to continue from here

Comment: It is absolutely NOT the case that $\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}=\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n-k}$ in general.  Are you thinking of $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$?

Comment: The hint is good. Please write down what Newton's binomial theorem is, edit that in to your post, and think about how Newton's binomial theorem can be applied to your summation.

Comment: You might also want to remind yourself of the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: @NickPeterson, oh yeah I was thinking of $\begin{pmatrix}n \\ k\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}n \\ n-k\end{pmatrix} $ with $n = \frac{1}{2}$  but writing this down, I just realized $n \neq \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

We know from the binomial theorem that,
$$
(1+x)^{1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}x^k
$$
(for suitable $x$).

This means, in particular, that
$$
1+x=(1+x)^{1/2}\cdot(1+x)^{1/2}=\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}x^k\right]^2.
$$
Note that for any $n\geq 2$, the coefficient by $x^n$ on the left side is $0$.  Therefore the coefficient by $x^n$ (where $n\geq2$) must also be $0$ on the right side.

The coefficient by $x^n$ in the right side can be computed using the Cauchy product.